# Is there any way to insert values into a table if the table is snapshottable?

Tags: hive, snapshot

I need to perform an **INSERT** operation into a table which is created upon a **snapshottable location**, is that possible?

(I've been working with Hive 1.1)

```
 CREATE TABLE tablename (x string, y string)
 LOCATION'/tmp/snapshots_test/';

 INSERT INTO TABLE  tablename VALUES('x','y');
```

where */tmp/snapshots_test/* is set as snapshottable:

```
hdfs dfsadmin -allowSnapshot /tmp/snapshots_test
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out that, if the table is partitioned, it is possible to perform an insert operation even if the location is a snapshottable directory, however, it might not work depending on the Hive version.

Anyway, it is always possible to delete just the file inside the snapshottable directory, so to avoid to delete all the directory through a Hive command.